# Laravel application connecting to outside database

Tags: php, laravel

I created an .env file in the root of the project. There I have these entries:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=mypassword
```

In config/database.php I have this that I guess is set by default by laravel:

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
```

When I run artisan to execute migration, with

```
php artisan migrate:fresh
```

I can see that my local database has been filled with tables.

What I do next is to request a creation of a user, with Auth located in /Http/Controllers/Api/AuthController.php.

However, I got an error saying:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'IP_ADDRESS' (using password: YES) (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where `email` = myemail@mail.com)
```

Why? Isn't it enough to have an .env with my local settings? I cannot understand where the ip address comes from. I searched all the project but the IP does not exist in the code.

A local form in a view goes to

```
http://localhost:8204/register
```

This is picked up in

```
routes/api.php
```

with this declaration:

```
Route::post('/register', [\App\Http\Controllers\Api\AuthController::class, 'register']);
```

The error above is printed by this file:

```
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:692
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using special characters on password put it inside `" "`.

Make sure you are using the right credentials too.

Try to run `php artisan config:clear` as well

Comment: No special characters. I run the config:clear. I also was unsure about the filename. I have tried with: ".env" and with ".env.local.php" but still getting the same error with unknown ip address.

Comment: the `.env` is correct. Have you created the database with the name `laravel` , as you have specified at DB_DATABASE ?

Comment: Yes I did. And artisan migrate is working and filling database with tables.

Comment: Okay, `What I do next is to request a creation of a user, with Auth located in /Http/Controllers/Api/AuthController.php.`
What do you mean with this, can you show some code

Comment: Basically I have a local form that goes to /register. In routes/api.php it has been declared with this: Route::post('/register', [\App\Http\Controllers\Api\AuthController::class, 'register']); Somewhere in the controller it uses Illuminate\Database\ and from there an error is generated from Illuminate\Database\ QueryException. The error is in the question.

Comment: Okay, i see now. Please update the thread with the code on your controller, so I can locate the problem exactly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233803/discussion-between-work-service-and-oderfla).

Answer (score 0):

The application was running in docker container. The .env file was wrong as it was pointing to my host database. When inside the container and the app, there was not database set up correctly. Thats why it did not work.